# Join multiple tables in Microsoft SQL Server where there is only one line match from table 1 and multiple lines from table 2 and 3

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am stuck on something, which I have never used in my 10 years of SQL. I thought it would be useful if there was someway of doing this. Firstly I am running SQL Server Express (latest free version) on Windows. To talk to the database I am using SSMS.

There are three tables/queries.

- 1 table **(A)** has one data value I want to pull through.
- 2 tables **(B)/(C)** have multiple values.
- Column common to all tables is `CAMPAIGN NAME`
- Column common to (B)/(C) is `PRODUCT NAME`

This is an example of the data:

[image: TABLE 1 / QUERY 1]

[image: TABLE 2 / QUERY 2]

[image: TABLE 3 / QUERY 3]

**OUTPUT GOAL**

[image]

I have tried the following:

- `UNION ALL` (but this does not assist when I want to calculate AMOUNT - MARKETING - TOTAL INVESTMENT
- I tried `PARTITION` (but I simple could now get it to work.
- If I use joins, it brings through a head count / total investment and marketing cost per product, which when using `SUM` brings through the incorrect values for head count / total investment and marketing cost vs total amount, quantity.
- I tried splitting the costs based on Quantity / Total Quantity or Amount / Total Amount, but the cost associated with the product is not correct or directly relating to the product this way.

Am I trying to do something impossible, or is there a way to do this in SQL?

Comment: can you please show us your SQL code that you have used to generate the results you are seeing, and also re-create this problem in a SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/ to enable us to help you

Comment: Your desired results are not in the structure of a SQL result set -- which consists of *rows* and *columns*.  I think you need to clarify your question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the desired output as you state isnt a sql format, and if a query is built to get the desired output there will be a lot of duplicated information.  This would possibly be better in a SSRS report where items can be grouped in the fashion the OP wants, but thats an entirely different question

Comment: @Simon Price. That makes sense. I guess this is why I cannot find a solution on the net on Query/CTE. The only way I can see around this problem is combining Tables (B & C) first (Multiple vs Multiple). Then aggregate that answer to one line which has CAMPAIGN (Table D). Then match Table A to Table D (Single to Single).. Then I can do the calculations on the totals. Then UNION back to Tables (A & B & C) based on CAMPAIGN name.

Answer (score 0):

The following comes pretty close to what you want:

```
select . . .   -- select the columns you want here
from a join
     b
     on b.campaign_name = a.campaign_name join
     c
     on c.campaign_name = b.campaign_name and
        c.product_name = b.product_name;
```

This produces a result set with a separate row for each campaign/product.